# c# equivalent of Numpy Where

Tags: c#, boolean, boolean-expression

How can I expand the following example to return an array of bool:

For example;

```
int[] data = { 1, 2, 5, 6 };
int[] data1 = { 2, 4, 6, 1};
int[] data2 = { 3, 2, 3, 0};
var results = Enumerable.Range(0, data.Length).Where(i => data[i] > 2 && data1[i] < 7 && data2[i] > 1 );
```

obtained results = `{ 2 }` which is the index on all three arrays satisfying their respective conditions

Intended result: `{False, False, True, False}` --> How can this result form.

Currently used method (verbose not neat):

```
for(int j = 0; j < h1.Length; j++)
            {
                if (h1[j] < 0.0 && h2[j] > 0.0 && h3[j] > threshold == true)
                {
                    result[j] = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    result[j] = false;
                }
            }
```

Reference: [[1]](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `Where()` to filter the collection, use `Select()` to project the results:

```
var results = Enumerable.Range(0, data.Length).Select(i => data[i] > 2 && data1[i] < 7 && data2[i] > 1);
```